# Why is my discord.js bot not responding to ";say (content)"

Tags: javascript, npm, bots, discord.js

I am coding a bot on discord called LowerBot, it is made in javascript and is using npm and discord.js. If somebody can pinpoint exactly where my bot went wrong that would be nice.

Here is my code:

```js
function getAfterSpace(str) {
    return str.split(' ')[1]; // get after space
}
client.on("message", msg => {
    if (msg.content.toLowerCase().includes === ";say ") {
        msg.channel.send(`${getAfterSpace(msg.content)}`)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `includes` is a method and you are comparing against the method actual method and not an invocation of it.

It should be `msg.content.toLowerCase().includes(";say ")` instead.

Comment: Ok well that kinda worked but now im suffering from another problem which I will probably ask on here in a second, my bot is only saying the first word that comes after the space between ;say and the content itself. so if i type ";say Hi there", it will just respond with "Hi". y i k e s

Comment: NVM I can only post every 90 minutes, oof.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it, but this is what I would do:

```js
if(message.content.toLowerCase.StartsWith(";say") {
   let result = message.content.split(" "); // creates an array of each word
   result = result.slice(1); // removes first entry (";say");
   result = result.join(" "); // combines each object in the array into a string. each object is separated by a space.
}
```